# Отладка работы кода в PyCharm

Tags: python, циклы, pycharm

Пользуюсь PyCharm.
Мой код состоит из 80 строк, в нем несколько внутренних циклов с операторами break, if и один "внешний" который должен повторять работу программы с заданным интервалом.
Мне нужно увидеть, какой цикл работает в данный момент, то есть как работает код по строкам, в реальном времени отследить всю работу каждого цикла, понять на чем у меня все останавливается.
Как это можно сделать в этой программе?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте поствить брейкпоинт и запустить программу в режиме отладки. Потом можно будет вручную пройтись по программе построчно и там уже можно будет посмотреть как меняются переменные и по какому пути в принципе идёт выполнение.

Answer (score 0):

иследуй средста отладки выбраного тобой ИДЕ. если лень изучать, используй print - тоже не плохой способ отладки и контроля. а в целом могу сказать, что я взлянул на твой код и могу сказать что как то не по питоновски он написан и много чего не указано... так что могу предложить только print ()

Answer (score 0):

В первую очередь нужно настроить окружение, чтобы дебажить, а именно Interpreter. К счастью, есть туториалы индусов на ютюбе, вот тут всё пошагово: [пример](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W8C097f6Hcg)

После этого в коде желательно объявить главную функцию, откуда Вы сможете вызывать другие функции, классы и другие сущности где у Вас лежит код. Вот так это выглядит:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #тут вызываете Ваш код
    pass
```

В Pycharm можно просто написать `main` и он автоматически выведет этот код выше.
[image: это точка входа]

Можно нажать на зелёный треугольник и он выполнит сразу весь код, а чтобы отлаживать- нужно поставить точку останова Просто сбоку возле номера строки нажимаете и появляется [image: точка остановки]

После чего нажмите на [image: "зелёного жука"]

и вуаля, Вы в режиме отладки. Ну а внизу стрелочками можно "ходить" по строчкам[image: "ходить" по строчкам]